# Synchronous and Asynchronous Code in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and is trying to understand how to better structure codes in TS.

Basically, I plan to have a FileReader class (synchronous) and an ApiFileReader class (asynchronous) which both inherits from a Reader class. I like both ApiFileReader and FileReader to be able to dump their return values into a data variable which can either be a string or array of posts which I can access by calling the data property of the inherited classes. Is that possible since one is synchronous and the other asynchronous? What is the best way to structure such sync and async codes using Typescript?

I tried below method of structuring the codes but it is erroneous. In index.ts file, apiFileReader.data returns an empty array instead of an array populated with posts

Appreciate those experienced with Typescript can provide some guidance on this matter. Thanks in advance

**Index.ts**

```
import { ApiFileReader } from "./inheritance/ApiFileReader";

//! API FILE READER
const apiFileReader = new ApiFileReader();

apiFileReader.readDataAsync();
console.log(apiFileReader.data); // returns an empty array
```

**ApiFileReader.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";

import { Reader } from "./Reader";
import { Post } from "./types/Post";

export class ApiFileReader extends Reader {
  data: Post[] = [];

  async readDataAsync(): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
      console.log("res ", res);
      this.data = res.data;
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  logData(): void {}
}
```

**FileReader.ts**

```
import fs from "fs";

import { Reader } from "./Reader";

export class CustomFileReader extends Reader {
  data: string = "";

  logData(): void {
    this.data = fs.readFileSync("note.doc", "utf-8");
  }
}
```

**Reader.ts**

```
import { Post } from "./types/Post";

export abstract class Reader {
  abstract data: string | Post[];

  abstract logData(): void;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is that possible since one is synchronous and the other asynchronous? What is the best way to structure such sync and async codes using Typescript?

You can make both functions async so that both will return a Promise. The function that uses sync code will return already resolved Promise e.g. `return Promise.resolve(your-sync-data)`.

Actually you don't even need to do that, just mark the sync code with `async` keyword:

```js
async function f() {
  return 5;              // what actually gets returned:  return Promise.resolve(5);
}
f().then(data => console.log(data));      // prints 5
```

> I tried below method of structuring the codes but it is erroneous. In index.ts file, apiFileReader.data returns an empty array instead of an array populated with posts

This code

```js
apiFileReader.readDataAsync();
```

doesn't await for the Promise returned by `readDataAsync()`. Instead of awaiting it executes immediately

```js
console.log(apiFileReader.data); // returns an empty array
```

and the array is empty because the data is not there yet.